# Git Push Error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

How to resolve
EmptyThrowable: Repository not found for root /path local, error while pushing my code on git don't know why I am getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you are not login your github account correctly. Login again and try.

Comment: it is showing when I am adding java class to git.

Comment: are you pulled that project ??

Comment: No pushing that project to the git

Comment: Go to VCS >Im ported into Version Control> Create Git Repo after it you can upload